# Get value of array by key

Tags: android, json

I get JSon from url:

PHP output:

```
{"error":"true","code":"inValid"}
```

Android code :

```
JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(result); // result is output php
JSONArray tasks = jsonRootObject.optJSONArray("error");
```

But not return value of error. I want get TRUE value from ERROR key

Comment: try to use  jsonRootObject.optString("error");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

**FYI**

In general all the **JSON** nodes will start with a square bracket or with a curly bracket. The difference between **[** and **{** is, the square bracket **([)** represents starting of an **`JSONArray`** node whereas curly bracket **({)** represents **`JSONObject`**. So while accessing these nodes we need to call appropriate method to access the data.

```
JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(result);

try 
{
   String strError = jsonRootObject.getString("error");
   String strCode = jsonRootObject.getString("code");

   Log.i("Error",":"+strError);
   Log.i("Code",":"+strCode);
}
catch (JSONException e) 
{
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried getString:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(result);
JSONObject jObj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
String mError = jObj.getString("error");
```